# ionic 3 angular styling mydatepicker component

Tags: css, ionic3

This seems to be some css issue and some guru would know how to fix right away.

I am using https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker which works as i require except i need to make some layout changes to the input box.

i am able to see desired changes if i do that in the chrome browser via developer tools but not able to get them working by applying the css.

so if you take a look at the screenshot: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2dhri8ylss3pfgd/Screenshot%202017-09-30%2018.27.41.png?dl=0

i need to set the height to 25px rather 34px.

try to override class like .selectiongroup etc. doesnt help

Answer (score 0):

you should use the height attribute to override input height.

```
private myOptions: IMyDpOptions  = {
    firstDayOfWeek: 'su',
    editableDateField: false,
    openSelectorOnInputClick: true,
    height: '25px'
};

 <my-date-picker [options]="myOptions" [(ngModel)]="XYZ" (dateChanged)="XYZ($event)"></my-date-picker>
```